# Windows Night Light Auto Triggers

Tags: windows-10

A day before, I found that my screen was yellow. I found that 'Night light' was turned on in Windows 10. Today, at the same time, it happened again. I am pretty sure that there is no schedule set for Night light. What might be the problem?

Comment: There is a schedule for you. Start, Settings, search for Night Light Settings.  On the screen that comes up, you can turn it ON or OFF and below that you can set a schedule for it.

Comment: @John I have clearly specified that there is no schedule set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check 'Night light' is set to off:

[image]

Then make sure 'Schedule night light' in 'Night light settings' is also set to off:

[image]

If 'Night light' is always turning on at the same time every day, then it is most likely that 'Night light' schedule is active, and this step should resolve the problem.

**If this doesn't work, then you can always just set your 'Night light' strength to zero.**

Comment: I have clearly specified that there is no schedule set. The last line was a pretty clever solution. Please remove that schedule part and I will select it as answer.

Comment: You never 'clearly specified' this. You said, and I quote, you were "pretty sure" you hadn't set a schedule. "Pretty sure" is not a definitive answer.

Comment: And also, this question is here for the informational purposes of others; others may want to read this answer if they have a similar problem to yours.